# Circle tangent to ellipse

Tags: circles, conic-sections

A small circle is tangent to the lower right quarter of a larger ellipse. The ellipse is straight (not rotated), and its lowest point is centered at origo.

The following is given:
"a", the axis of the ellipse along the x axis.
"b", the axis of the ellipse along the y axis.
"r", the radius of the circle.
"h", the top y coordinate of the circle.

I am seeking the x coordinate of the tangent point between the ellipse and the circle as a function of a, b, r and h.

[image: figure]

Comment: On MathSE, we'd like to see effort. What have you tried?

Comment: I end up in various expressions dependent on the normal vectors angle, and cannot seem to find expressions without the angle.

Comment: From the information you've got, you can write down an equation for the ellipse. Let $u$ be the $x$-coordinate of the centre of the circle, and you can write down an equation for the circle in terms of $u$, $r$ and $h$. Eliminate $y$ from these and you have an equation for the $x$-coordinate of the point of tangency. What sort of equation is this? How many roots should it have? How can you use that to solve for $u$ and finally $x$?

Comment: I get an equation that I presume I can rewrite to isolate x on one side, so that it is dependent on u. However I cannot express u without using the tangents angle. So for me this hint is only a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Seems like combining the equation of the circle to the ellipse, with equating the derivative of both, will give me two equations that can be used to nest out the value of x. However the expressions are quite hairy.

Comment: Ellipse = Circe:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=-b*Divide%5BSqrt%5BPower%5Ba%2C2%5D-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2Ca%5D%2Bb%3DSqrt%5BPower%5Br%2C2%5D+-+Power%5B%5C%2840%29x+-+u%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D+-+r+%2B+h+

Comment: Derivative of Ellipse = Derivative of Circle:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bb+x%2Ca+Sqrt%5BPower%5Ba%2C2%5D-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%5D%3DDivide%5Bu+-+x%2CSqrt%5BPower%5Br%2C2%5D-Power%5B%5C%2840%29u-x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%5D

Comment: From the point of tangency $(u,v)$ on the ellipse, find the outward pointing normal vector. Translate from $(u,v)$ by a distance $r$ in that direction to get the center of the circle. go up $r$ to find the top $y$ coordinate on the circle. Call that $h$. Solve for the point of tangency from $a, b, h, r$.

Comment: @eirirlar: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please edit your question to include your equations (formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409), please) in the body. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) This will help people avoid wasting time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand. ... Good luck!

Comment: I'm going to accept Hosams answer and award the bounty to Cesaro. I believe Hosams answer was the closest to give a function for the x value dependent on a, b, r and h. Cesaros answer had a more intuitive approach, and the code to support it was great, however it did not result in an algebraic expression of a, b, r and h. Both answers were very useful to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ellipse has the equation

$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y - b)^2}{b^2} = 1 \hspace{20pt}(1)$

Now let the circle have a center $(p, q)$, then $q = h - r$, and its equation is

$ (x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 = r^2 \hspace{20pt}(2)$

The unknowns here are $x, y, p$

In addition to the above two equations, we know that the normal to the ellipse at $(x,y)$ and the normal to the circle at the same point, are aligned.

The normal vector (also called gradient) of a function of two variables, $F(x,y) = 0$ is given by $N = ( \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} , \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y})$.

Hence, the normal vector to the ellipse is

$N_1 = (N_{1x}, N_{1y}) =  \left( \dfrac{2 x}{ a^2} , \dfrac{2 (y - b)}{b^2} \right) $

similarly, the normal vector to the circle is

$N_2 = (N_{2x}, N_{2y}) =  ( 2 (x - p) , 2 (y - q) ) $

If $N_1$ is aligned with $N_2$ then

$ N_1 = k N_2 $

where $k$ is a constant.

Hence,

$(N_{1x} , N_{1y} ) = k (N_{2x}, N_{2y} ) $

From which,

$ k = \dfrac{N_{1x}}{N_{2x}} = \dfrac{N_{1y}}{N_{2y}} $

Using cross multiplication on the equality on the right of the above equation, we obtain,

$ N_{1x} N_{2y} = N_{2x} N_{1y} $

Substituting the expressions for $N_{1x}, N_{1y}, N_{2x}, N_{2y}$, gives us,

$ \dfrac{2 x}{ a^2} \cdot 2 (y - q) = 2 (x - p) \cdot \dfrac{2 (y - b)}{b^2}  $

Dividing the whole equation by $4$ to cancel the $2$'s, and then multiplying through by $a^2 b^2$ gives us,

$ b^2 x (y - q) = a^2 (x - p) (y - b) \hspace{20pt}(3)$

Now, we'll to eliminate $x$ and $(x - p)$ from equation $(3)$

First square equation $(3)$, this gives us,

$ b^4 x^2 (y - q)^2 = a^4 (x - p)^2 (y - b)^2 \hspace{20pt}(4) $

From equation $(1)$,

$ x^2 = a^2 \left(1 - \dfrac{(y - b)^2}{b^2} \right) \hspace{20pt}(5) $

And, from equation $(2)$,

$ (x - p)^2 =  r^2 - (y - q)^2  \hspace{20pt}(6)$

Substitute $(5)$ and $(6)$ into $(4)$.  This gives

$ b^4 (y - q)^2 a^2 \left(1 - \dfrac{(y - b)^2}{b^2} \right) = a^4 (y - b)^2 (r^2 - (y - q)^2 ) \hspace{20pt} (7) $

This simplifies to

$ b^2 (y - q)^2 ( - y^2 + 2 y b ) = a^2 (y - b)^2 (r^2 - (y - q)^2 ) \hspace{20pt}(8)$

Expanding equation $(8)$, yields the quartic polynomial equation:

$ a_4 y^4 + a_3 y^3 + a_2 y^2 + a_1 y + a_0 = 0 \hspace{20pt} (9)$

where

$a_4 = b ^ 2 - a ^ 2 $

$a_3 = 2  (b + q)  (a ^ 2 - b ^ 2) $

$a_2 = a ^ 2  (r ^ 2 - q ^ 2 - b ^ 2 - 4  b  q) - b ^ 2  (-q ^ 2 - 4  b  q) $

$a_1 = a ^ 2  (2  b  (q ^ 2 - r ^ 2) + 2 q  b ^ 2) - 2 b ^ 3   q ^ 2$

$a_0 = a ^ 2  b ^ 2  (r ^ 2 - q ^ 2) $

The roots of this quartic polynomial can be solved by standard routines in any math library.  These routines find the exact value of the root using exact formulas for the quartic polynomial roots that depend only on the coeffcients $a_4$ through $a_0$.  The exact way these roots are calculated is beyond the scope of this answer.  The interested reader is referred to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation).

To select the correct root, note that

$ x = a \sqrt{ 1 - \dfrac{(y - b)^2}{b^2} } \hspace{20pt}(10) $

Because we know that $ x \gt 0 $, while from equation $(6)$, and since $p \gt x$,

$ (x - p) = - \sqrt{ r^2 - (y - q)^2 } \lt 0  \hspace{20pt}(6)$

Now look at equation $(3)$

$ b^2 x (y - q) = a^2 (x - p) (y - b) $

Since we want tangency below the line $y = b $, then we firstly require that $ (y - b) \lt 0$, this will make the right hand side positive.  Now looking at the left hand side, we see that $x \gt 0$, so we must require that $ y \gt q $.  Hence, in summary we will select $y$ such that $ q \lt y \lt b $.  Once we have found $y$, then the calculation of $x$ and $p$ follows as stated above.

Here is an example, where $a = 4, b = 8, r = 2 , h = 5 $.

Running a small code which calls a quartic polynomial root finder, and after selecting the appropriate $y$, the program gives the tangent point as $(x,y)$ and center of circle $(p, q)$ with

$ x = 3.34773271274127 $

$ y = 3.62155932595085 $

$ p = 5.24869667987045 $

$ q = 3 $

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot. There are some leaps in the logic that I find a bit hard to follow: the normal vector to the circle and ellipse is just given in vector form without explanation of a formula; and the jump from N1 and N2 which are in vector form over to the combined normal vectors is not explained. Regarding equation (9), you refer to solving roots in a math library. Do you mean to solve algebraically or numerically? Finally, is it possible to get the correct root of the quartic stated algebraically?

Comment: @eirirlar I've updated my solution to answer your remarks.  As for the roots of a quartic polynomial, you need to find all the possible roots, and this is best done by calling a polynomial root finder routine from a library, e.g. Mathematica, or Wolframalpha.com,  because attempting to solve numerically, gives you one root at a time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I managed to scramble together some sympy Python code based on your answer:
https://pastebin.com/2Ya6kvNi

The algebraic expressions are also extractable, however they are as expected horrific. With your input I get the same results as you posted.

Answer (score 4):

The ellipse $E_{x,y}\to \left(\frac xa\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-b}{b}\right)^2=1$ in polar coordinates reads

$$
E_{\theta}\to\cases{x=a\cos\theta\\ y = b+b\sin\theta}
$$

The normal to $E_{x,y}$ is given by

$$
\vec n_{x,y}= \left(\frac{x}{a^2 \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^4}+\frac{(b-y)^2}{b^4}}},\frac{y-b}{b^2 \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^4}+\frac{(b-y)^2}{b^4}}}\right)
$$

and consequently

$$
\vec n_{\theta} = \left(\frac{\cos \theta }{a \sqrt{\frac{\cos ^2\theta }{a^2}+\frac{\sin ^2\theta }{b^2}}},\frac{\sin \theta }{b
   \sqrt{\frac{\cos ^2\theta }{a^2}+\frac{\sin ^2\theta }{b^2}}}\right)
$$

then

$$
\mathcal{E}_{\theta} = \left(a \cos\theta,b+b\sin\theta\right)+ r \vec n_{\theta}
$$

describes a set of points expanded from $E_{\theta}$ in the normal direction, with length $r$.

Now $\mathcal{E}_{\theta}$ intersects with the line $y = h - r$ where the circle center should be located, or better:

$$
b+b\sin\theta+\frac{r\sin \theta }{b\sqrt{\frac{\cos ^2\theta }{a^2}+\frac{\sin ^2\theta }{b^2}}}= h-r
$$

or

$$
f(\theta)=b(1+\sin\theta)+\frac{r a\sin\theta}{\sqrt{b^2-(b^2-a^2)\sin^2\theta}}-h+r=0
$$

now choosing an iterative process like Newton's to approximate an initial guess,

$$
\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k - f(\theta_k)/f'(\theta_k)
$$

we are done.

Taking $a=1,b=2,h=1/3, r=1/5$ and $\theta_0=0$ in three iterations we obtain $\theta = -0.8675956$.  Follows a graphic showing $E_{\theta}$ yellow continuous, $\mathcal{E}_{\theta}$ yellow dashed, $y=h-r$ in blue dashed and in red the circle center calculated as $(0.647982738, 0.133333333)$.

[image]

Attached a python script to perform the calculations

```
import math

a = 1
b = 2
h = 1./3.
r = 0.2
theta0 = 0.
n = 7
error = 0.0000001

def Phi(theta):
    s = math.sin(theta)
    c = math.cos(theta)
    p1 = b**2-(b**2 - a**2)*s**2
    p2 = a*r/math.sqrt(p1) + b
    p3 = s*p2 + b - h + r
    p4 = c*p2 - a*r*(a**2 - b**2)*s**2*c/math.sqrt(p1)**3
    return theta - p3/p4


for k in range(n):
    theta1 = Phi(theta0)
    if abs(theta1-theta0) < error:
        print("result in ", k, "iterations. theta  = ", theta1)
        c = math.cos(theta1)
        s = math.sin(theta1)
        x0 = a*c + r*c*b/math.sqrt(a**2*s**2 + b**2*c**2)
        y0 = b + s*(b + a*r/math.sqrt(a**2*s**2 + b**2*c**2))
        print("circle center = (", x0, y0, ")")
        break
    theta0 = theta1
```

Comment: I really like the approach of drawing a larger ellipse around that goes through the circles origo! The first line: "Ex,y→(x/a)^2+(y−bb)=1" ; (x-b)/b is supposed to be squared, no? The formula for the normal vector to the ellipse, where does that come from? Comparing to the other answer's normal vector definition, I have trouble understanding the divisor.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to square the second term. Thanks. Regarding the normal, giving a vector with components $\vec v = (x, y)$ the normalized vector is $\hat v = \frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|} = (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$. The normalization is included to assure that the absolute value/length/modulus is unitary.

Comment: Attached a python script to perform the calculations.